# Rails app not working with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to use sendgrid to send confirmation emails to users after they sign up. Everything was working before I tried configuring send grid, but now as soon as a user tries to sign up, I get the heroku error message to check the logs. I don't know what to make of the logs because every single thing is just a fatal error:

```
 2016-09-24T02:33:00.151277+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-24T02:33:00.151247 #3] FATAL -- : [e27b857c-d6d7-4e1d-a859-0abf408efa52]   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer- 5.0.0.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:96:in `block in deliver_now'
2016-09-24T02:33:00.151307+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-24T02:33:00.151277  #3]     FATAL -- : [e27b857c-d6d7-4e1d-a859-0abf408efa52]  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer- 5.0.0.1/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:15:in `handle_exceptions'
2016-09-24T02:33:00.151373+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-24T02:33:00.151307 #3] FATAL -- : [e27b857c-d6d7-4e1d-a859-0abf408efa52] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-5.0.0.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:95:in `deliver_now'
2016-09-24T02:33:00.151406+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-24T02:33:00.151374 #3] FATAL -- : [e27b857c-d6d7-4e1d-a859-0abf408efa52] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:191:in `send_devise_notification'
```

EDIT: Going back in the logs I  found these

```
2016-09-  24T05:30:26.437967+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-24T05:30:26.438280+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-09-24T05:30:26.438213 #3]  INFO -- : [7bde114c-61f1-45c8-9660-f4ce4dc1e7c1] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
2016-09-24T05:30:26.440494+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-24T05:30:26.440427 #3] FATAL -- : [7bde114c-61f1-45c8-9660-f4ce4dc1e7c1]   
2016-09-24T05:30:26.440562+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-24T05:30:26.440501 #3] FATAL -- : [7bde114c-61f1-45c8-9660-f4ce4dc1e7c1] Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):
```

---

These are just the first few. I feel like they're not telling me enough to figure out how to fix the problem.

The link to the repository if that helps at all:
    https://github.com/hbrodsk1/facebook

Any guidance would be awesome because I'm truly stuck at this point.

Comment: You haven't shown the actual error...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your SENDGRID USERNAME and PASSWORD in the rails console through "heroku config:set"? And also including your SENDGRID USERNAME and PASSWORD in your .bashrc file (if you are on c9). Maybe you might like to share what set up procedures you have done for sendgrid?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the steps you have taken up till this point which resulted in the error for heroku?

Comment: Yes, I had deployed it earlier in the day and it was fully functional, but after adding the sendgrid gem, I tried configuring my mailers and then deployed again which resulted in the errors. I will post my config files in an edit.

Comment: I think you should add into the edit your configuration steps too. Something probably went wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set sendgrid username and password in heroku config or in production.rb file of your rails application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't configured the production environment to use Sendgrid for your mailer. 
Adding this to your production.rb in the config/environments folder should be the first step. That is as long as you define `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` somewhere in the code.

`config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }`

This error is coming up because Devise is attempting to handle a mailer event but can't find the instructions on how to process the mailer for the production environment. You've defined this in the local/development environment already so that's why it works locally. This should at least point you in the correct direction.

Check this out as a resource too: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html#-Configure-ActionMailer-to-Use-SendGrid

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had to reset my send grid environment username from my console and it worked. Thank you for all of your responses and help though.